# Simple Login Form in cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

**It would be appropriate to include significant account-specific features from Amazon and not just an authentication method in order to be in compliance. You may also implement your own optional registration, iCloud or Game Center as another option.**

Great Apple rejected my game 6 times due the above reason, first of all, they rejected my game because they said it need a user registration to save purchased data even if user changed the device and they can access all purchased things if he have a registered user id with the game, i done the user registration using amazon login sdk, and three other games approved with the amazon login, but this game rejecting showing the above reason., is there any sample login view form for cocos2d for user registration? i dont know how can we do a login with iCloud or game centre. all i want to do is a simple login form for cocos2d.IS there any samples out there how to make a login form using iCloud or game centre ,, i have some ,but they al are native iOS sample, cocos2d samples is not there.

hope anyone can help me to get rid of this situation.,